# Issues with Long in Hashtable Java

Tags: java, hashtable, long-integer

Apparently, I am unable to store a Long value in a hashtable.

See the code below:

```
//create a hashtable of type <String, Long>
Hashtable <String, Long> universalTable = new Hashtable <String, Long> ();

universalTable.put("HEADS", new Long(0)); // this works fine
```

I pass this table in the constructor for `DoFlip`:

```
DoFlip doFlip = new DoFlip(100000000, universalTable);
```

Inside `DoFlip`:

```
Hashtable table; // pointer to hash map
long iterations = 0; // number of iterations

DoFlip(long iterations, Hashtable table){
    this.iterations = iterations;
    this.table = table;
}
```

This class implements Runnable. The `run()` method is as follows—

```
public void run(){
    while(this.iterations > 0){
        // do some stuff
        this.heads ++;
        this.iterations --;
    }
    updateStats();
}

public void updateStats(){
    Long nHeads = (Long)this.table.get("HEADS");
    this.table.put("HEADS", nHeads); // ISSUE HERE
}
```

I get the following warning/error. Looks like a warning but I don't want this.

```
Note: File.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

When I recompile:

```
File.java:92: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
            this.table.put("HEADS", nHeads);
                          ^
1 warning
```

I am unsure why this is the case. Firstly, there isn't any need to type cast `nHeads`. But I still do it and it doesn't work.

Note: I am not good in Java at all. :/

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The hashtable isn't generic in DoFlip, and a warning isn't an error.

Comment: "hashtable isn't generic in DoFlip" Can you please elaborate? Also, I do understand it's a warning (as I mention it). I want to understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This warning indicates that you are using a raw type. Replace

```
DoFlip(long iterations, Hashtable table){
```

with

```
DoFlip(long iterations, Hashtable<String, Long> table) {
```

such that it contains the generics similar to `universalTable`. Also include the generics in the initial declaration.

Side note:

- `Hashtable` is a pretty old `Collection` and has been replaced by `HashMap`.

Comment: This helped too. I had two generic declarations. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the heads. As for `DoFlip` rather than `doFlip`, `DoFlip` is a static class and therefore that's the constructor as well.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a warning, telling you that you are mixing generic and non-generic containers. This is allowed, but the compiler can do a better job at type checking if you use generics everywhere in your code.

To fix this warning, you need to change

```
Hashtable table;
```

for

```
Hashtable<String, Long> table;
```

in declarations inside `DoFlip`.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents:

Firstly, if you are building some performance sensitive application and you want to avoid the conversion between Long and long primitive, consider using [trove4j](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) collection library. It's a primitive based one with good quality.

Secondly, your DoFlip should be declared as

```
DoFlip(long iterations, Hashtable<String, Long> table){
    this.iterations = iterations;
    this.table = table;
}
```

and problem solved.

Enjoy.

Comment: Yes, I am building a performance based application. Will look out for trove4j. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reassure the compiler that your HashMaps are all from Strings to Longs. You did it here:

```
Hashtable <String, Long> universalTable = new Hashtable <String, Long> ();
```

... but not here:

```
Hashtable table; // pointer to hash map
---
DoFlip(long iterations, Hashtable table){
```

So do:

```
Hashtable<String, Long> table;
---
DoFlip(long iterations, Hashtable<String, Long> table){
```

...and there shall be no more automated panic that you'll put the wrong types of objects in `table` at runtime, since now the compiler can check that you always use the ones you intended (i.e. the ones specified in the brackets).

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning from compiler that you are `mixing generic and non-generic containers`

You could do either of the following steps to make it disappear

1)you need to change

```
Hashtable table;
```

for

```
Hashtable<String, Long> table;
```

OR

2)You can use SuppressWarning annotation to suppress the warning

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void updateStats(){
    Long nHeads = (Long)this.table.get("HEADS");
    this.table.put("HEADS", nHeads); // ISSUE HERE
}
```